# ServiceNow CMDB get CI Relationships data - API

Tags: servicenow-rest-api, cmdb

API Question for CMDB ServiceNow,

Trying to GET data from the **CI Relationships** tab that is within a **Business AP** (as presented in the UI) that falls under a business owner.

Steps:

1. Getting the business **owner ID**:

`GET https://xxx.service-now.com/api/now/table/sys_user?sysparm_query=email%3D{xxxx.com}&sysparm_limit=1`

2. Getting the Business Apps owned by the owner ID:

`GET https://xxx.service-now.com/api/now/table/cmdb_ci_business_app?sysparm_query=owned_by%3Da3e8xxxxxxxx6d19e484755b0d&sysparm_limit=10`

3. and how to get the data with the CI Relationships:

I tried;

`https://xxx.service-now.com/api/now/table/cmdb_rel_type?sysparm_query=sys_id%3D{ID}&sysparm_limit=10`

But I cannot find the link between a **Business App** and its **CI Relationship's** data

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Use cmdb_rel_ci (CI Relationships) instead of cmdb_rel_type (CI Relationship Type):

`GET https://xxx.service-now.com/api/now/table/cmdb_rel_ci?sysparm_query=parent%3D{PARENT_SYS_ID}&sysparm_limit=10`

Comment: cmdb_rel_ci - did the trick!  
Thanks a lot! :)